# can Vscode record my changings like visual stutio do when coding?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I know a theme of Vscode can perform like  visual stutio,
**dark(visual studio) theme** is wonderful!

[image]

but the same theme of  **Win vscode**  is different...

there are no lines to record what you've changed.

I want my vscode in windows can also have same behavior of theme Dark(visual stutio). 
Do you have some suggestions?

my vscode version in ubuntu is below, and my vscode in win is newest,

```
Version: 1.31.1
Commit: 1b8e8302e405050205e69b59abb3559592bb9e60
Date: 2019-02-12T02:19:29.629Z
Electron: 3.1.2
Chrome: 66.0.3359.181
Node.js: 10.2.0
V8: 6.6.346.32
OS: Linux x64 4.15.0-47-generic
```

Comment: I always believed that themes aren't anything more than kind of palettes for colors (and, may be, background images). For tracking of modifications, a built-in editor feature is necessary. I'm really not sure (I'm rather sure that not) whether themes does provide such extensions.

Comment: You probably should configure Git.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the theme. This feature works for on Windows, for any files added to a git repo.

Comment: I think You were Right! I'm ignorant